# Function detect in Features2d

Tags: c, opencv, detection

do anybody know, how the detect-function works? for example here:

```
Mat img = imread (...);    
SurfFeatureDetector detector(400); 
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(img, keypoints);
```

especially how it's writting in keypoints.

I need to write some coordinates in keypoints without using

```
detector.detect(...);
```

This doesn't work

```
keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(i,j);
```

---

**next problem:**
I have the function:

```
void trajkovic(Mat img, vector<KeyPoint> keypoints)
{    for( int i = 0; i < img.rows-3; i++ )
        for( int j = 0; j < img.cols-3; j++ )
        {   Point2f keyPointLocation(i, j);
            keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(keyPointLocation, 1)); } }

int main()
{   Mat img_object = imread( ".../box.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    Mat img_scene = imread( ".../box_in_scene.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;
    trajkovic(img_object, keypoints_object);
    trajkovic(img_scene, keypoints_scene);
```

- instead of ( *detector.detect( img_object, keypoints_object );* )

  ```
  //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
  SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

  Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

  extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
  extractor.compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

  //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
  FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
  std::vector< DMatch > matches;
  matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

  double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

  //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
  { double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
  }

  printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
  printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

  //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
  std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
  { if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
    { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
  }

  Mat img_matches;
  drawMatches( img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
               good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
               vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );


  //-- Localize the object from img_1 in img_2
  std::vector<Point2f> obj;
  std::vector<Point2f> scene;

  for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
  {
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
  }

  Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

  cvWaitKey(0);
  return 0;
  ```

  }

in findHomography i have an error: "Assertion failed (npoints >=0 && points2.Vector(2) == npoints)) in findHomography, file /modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp, line 1062"

what's wrong?
I guess that something wrong with

```
keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(keyPointLocation, 1));
```

thanks a lot

Comment: You should be calling `keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(i,j));`

Comment: i've got the same error, that doesn't matter Point2f keyPointLocation(i, j); keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(keyPointLocation, 1)); or keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(i,j,1));

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should go throw the opencv [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#KeyPoint). 
`cv::KeyPoint` is a structure to store points detected by `cv::FeatureDetector` object. It contains coordinates of the keypoint, diameter of the meaningfull neighborhood, orientation, and response. The computation of keypoints depends of the detector definition (Sift,Surf,Mser,...)

Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) !

Comment: "It contains coordinates of the keypoint, diameter of the meaningfull neighborhood, orientation, and response." for( int i = 0; i < img.rows-3; i++ ) 
        for( int j = 0; j < img.cols-3; j++ ); if (...)  keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(i,j,1); This one doesn't work anyway, what's wrong?

Comment: Probably i don't understand the process, how to write in cv::KeyPoint, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually create [KeyPoint's](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=keypoint#KeyPoint), Here is a small sample to get you started:

```
vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        Point2f keyPointLocation(i, j);
        float meaningfulNeighborhoodDiameter = 5.0;
        keyPoints.push_back(KeyPoint(keyPointLocation, meaningfulNeighborhoodDiameter));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: so this, almost the same: keypoints.push_back(KeyPoint(i,j, 5.0); and i still have an errorwith the function, i'll show the text in my edited question

Comment: No. That is not the same. `KeyPoint` takes a `Point2f` object not two integer values. So, you could do the following `keyPoints.push_back(Point2f(i, j), 5.0);`.